# Create a Gradient For this button

Tags: html, css

I was trying to achieve this effect for a background button, notices that the effect it's a like a wave. Is there a some way that i can defined a gradient or a css function to accomplish this?

[image]

The most that I can get it's a gradient for a vertical or horizontal line but not like a Wave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert in CSS, but here's my solution (pure CSS).
Tested only in FF.

[image: wave line pure CSS]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fzUVF/)

---

modified in accordance with the example:

[image: wave line pure CSS]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YPHKG/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this if its even possible with just CSS. The closest you could get is some combination of a :before and :after pseudo class each with their own radial gradient, but even then it won't match exactly.

You could also use multiple gradients stacked but again not an exact match.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you [CSS Gradient Button](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons) and [here](http://www.red-team-design.com/cross-browser-css-gradient-buttons)